# How To Use The Current Local Time of Day To Control A Process Without Dates

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi2

I need to stop a process at 8:00 PM PDT everyday or as soon as possible after 8:00 PM. I see a lot about other uses of the time function but the examples all seem to be a difference in time, the timing of something, or always have the date included.

Could someone please provide an example along the lines of how I make something like this work...?
if currenttime >= 8:00 PM PDT: 
     time.sleep(99999999)

And also, what will I need to import, and how do I do the import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up using a combination of hai tederry's answer and that found on http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/06/how-to-get-current-date-and-time-in/
resulting in:

```
import time                             # import time library               
import datetime                         # this is the way to import a module named datetime...
import pytz                             # imports Python time zone (needed to first do: sudo easy_install --pytz upgrade) 
now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'))
timenow = now.strftime("%I:%M %p")
print timenow
if timenow > "08:30 PM" and timenow < "08:45 PM":
   print "Programmed Pause"
   time.sleep(999999)
```

This creates a time only output in your local 12 hour format with AM/PM that can be used in if statements, etc.

Answer (score 1):

the method I know is:

```
import datetime #this is the way to import a module named datetime...
import time     #this module is used to sleep

a = str(datetime.datetime.now())   #a = '2016-03-27 00:20:28.107000' #for example
a = a.split(' ')[1]          #get rid of the date and keep only the '00:20:28.107000' part
if a.startwith('20:00'): time.sleep(3600*12) #sleep for 12 hours (43200 seconds)
```

hope this helps you

edit: change timezone to pdt:

```
import datetime,pytz #for python_TimeZone
a = str(datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'))) #basically get the time in the specified zone
#from here continue as above...
```

taken from: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/05/converting-time-zones-datetime-objects-python/

good luck (next time try searching it in google...)

Comment: yes, this information was very helpful. Thank you! Here is what I entered into my code, but sort of wish the format was PDT intead of GMT or UTC                                                                                         a = str(datetime.datetime.now())        
                a = a.split(' ')[1].split('.')[0]
                if a > '03:30:00' and a<'06:00:00':
                         time.sleep(999999)

Comment: I could not format the code correctly in my response above. I wonder if you could update your answer with what I put in my and perhaps expand it a bit on how to change the time format to local time instead of UTC/GMT. Thanks a bunch, hai tederry!

Comment: If unable to make it local time, that is ok too. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Mark sorry being late. i'v answered, however next time try this:   it's much faster

Comment: now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'))
                timenow = now.strftime("%I:%M %p")
                print timenow
                if timenow > "08:30 PM" and timenow < "08:45 PM":
                    print "Programmed Pause"
                    time.sleep(999999)